# $X_z=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} \Phi_t(z)$ has flow $\Phi_t$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a manifold, $\Phi_t, t\in \mathbb R$ a one parameter group of diffeomorphisms and $X$ a vector field on $M$ definied by $$X_z:=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} \Phi_t(z).$$
Show that $\Phi_t$ is the flow of $X$.

**own Ideas:**

Okay, since $\Phi_t$ is a one parameter group of diffeomorphisms we have

(1): $\Phi_a(\Phi_b(z))=\Phi_{a+b}(z)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb R$

(2): $\Phi_0(z)=$id$(z)$

We have to show that $$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(z)=X_{\Phi_t(z)}.$$

So since I can not insert $\Phi_t(z)$ into $X$ I think we have to look at $X_{\Phi_c(z)}$ with $c\in \mathbb R$. Then we get: $$X_{\Phi_c(z)}=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} \Phi_t(\Phi_c(z)) \overset{(1)}{=}\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} \Phi_{t+c}(z)$$

I do not know how to continue nor if this is the right way. Pls help.

Comment: That's actually it, $$\frac{d}{dt}\biggl\lvert_{t = 0} \Phi_{t+c}(z) = \frac{d}{dt}\biggl\lvert_{t = c} \Phi_t(z).$$

Comment: Okay, I get this. What I dont get is why $\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=c}\Phi_t(z) =\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(z)$.

Comment: It isn't quite, one is a single value, the other a function (of $t$), if we keep $z$ fixed. But $\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t(z) = X_{\Phi_t(z)}$ means nothing other than $$(\forall c)\Biggl(\frac{d}{dt}\biggl\lvert_{t = c} \Phi_t(z) = X_{\Phi_c(z)}\Biggr).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write instead
$$X_{\Phi_t(z)}=\frac{d}{ds}_{|s=0} \Phi_s(\Phi_t(z))=\frac{d}{ds}_{|s=0} \Phi_{s+t}(z)=\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t(z).$$

Comment: I understand the first two equalities, but why the last one holds? Maybe I'm confused: $\frac{d}{ds}_{|s=0}\Phi_{s+t}(z)$ means that I derive $\Phi_{s+t}$ for $s$ and then insert $0$ for $s$, while $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(z)$ is the derivation for $t$ of $\Phi_t$.

Comment: As in what @Daniel Fischer wrote, it is a change of variables: write $s+t=\tau$; then $$\frac{d}{ds}_{|s=0} \Phi_{s+t}(z)=\frac{d}{d\tau}_{|\tau=t} \Phi_\tau(z)\frac{d\tau}{ds}_{|s=0}=\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t(z),$$ since $\frac{d\tau}{ds}_{|s=0}=1$.